# Why is my avocado plant dying with brown, decaying leaves?

Tags: diagnosis, indoors, avocado

A few years ago I grew an avacado plant from some seed and some time later leaves started turning brown and fell from the plant. I tried a lot, but landed on the thought that perhaps since it has never been fertilized, it was dying.

So after repotting it for better drainage and what not, I bought some fertilizer, and things started to slow down. But Nancy the avacado plant is back at its favourite things to do, dying, being dramatic, and making me worried. I honestly have no idea what could be causing this. I water it once every two days (usually every day), with a cup or two of water. I hope the pictures provided can help you help me decide what to do to prevent its death.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try to give it less water, every day seems a bit much. Try to let the top layer of the soil to dry out (feel it with your fingers) before watering it again.

Comment: it looks etoliated as well.  Does it only live inside??

Comment: I think it just needs more space and sun. Plant Nancy outside.

Comment: graham chiu and rob, Nancy is strictly an indoor avacado . does she need solely more sun?

Comment: @ J Doe. I am sorry to break the news but Avacado is a tree (a very large tree) and it needs to be outside at some point. You might try a bonsai of some kind but I would say based on how large its gotten already it's too late for that.

Comment: When the plant wilts without warning signs from insect and drought, it is always a wise thing to inspect the roots. Normally it's a root stress. Overwatering, for instance, may reveal itself as decaying roots in a mushy potting soil. Stress may show-up sometime before rot becomes visible. Soil-dwelling pests & diseases may damage roots, but in containers, the roots environment problems prevail.

Answer (score 1):

I've been told to not have a plate under the pot. The water needs to drain through. Local nursery will even slash the side of the plastic container to help the water drain. Currently 1 of my avocado trees are struggling because of too much water... In the summer I water then every day, winter same amount every 3 days and it was still struggling!!!! Usually the issue is a water issue.